# ggplot2: passing a variable value to a text box

Tags: r, ggplot2

R experts,

I'm wondering if there is a way to pass a variable value to a text box. The code below is what I used to create maps. In the line with "annotate", I have to type state average value for each map. Because we have many similar maps using different variables, I'm wondering if there is a way to automatically populate the variable value in the text box? Similarly, in the line with "scale_fill_manual", I need to customize the legend label by typing numbers in the variable "quint", is there a more efficient way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

```
#quint is a quintile variable I developed from variable coef
ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data=RIalz_data, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=quint),size=0.3, color="#969696")+
  theme_void()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#4292C6", "#92C5DE", "#FEE391","#EC7014","#CA0020"), 
               labels=c("7.84%-11.90%","11.91%-13.50%","13.51%-14.70%","14.71%-15.40%","15.41%-22.90%"))+
  theme(legend.position=c(0.84,0.15), 
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"),
        legend.title = element_text(colour = 'black', size = 10), 
        legend.key.size = unit(0.8, "cm"),
        legend.box.margin = margin(2, 2, 2, 2))+
  annotate("text", x=-71.92, y=41.26, label="State Average: 13.9%", hjust=0, size = 5, fontface=2)
```

EDIT: I have attached a screenshot of the first few observations of the data frame [demo pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhwnQ.jpg) and below is the output for the first 20 rows. The variable stateav53 only has one value and that's the value I'm hoping to pass to the text box. Another variable 'quint' is the value I used to edit the legend.

```
dput(head(RIdata2,20))

structure(list(long = c(-71.32217025, -71.32217741, -71.32218078, 
-71.32217968, -71.32217042, -71.3221554, -71.32213002, -71.32209299, 
-71.32207521, -71.32206824, -71.32205179, -71.32202472, -71.32201494, 
-71.3219907, -71.32197626, -71.32194267, -71.32190906, -71.32189649, 
-71.32186853, -71.32183016), lat = c(41.76994015, 41.7699019, 
41.76986367, 41.76975468, 41.76967901, 41.76959771, 41.76951862, 
41.76940913, 41.7693335, 41.76931201, 41.76926145, 41.7691979, 
41.76916612, 41.7691061, 41.76908071, 41.76903135, 41.76897847, 
41.76895236, 41.76889874, 41.76884377), order = 1:20, hole = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE), piece = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74"), class = "factor"), id = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("1.1", "1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "1.6", "1.7", 
"1.8", "1.9", "1.10", "10.1", "10.2", "10.3", "10.4", "10.5", 
"10.6", "10.7", "10.8", "11.1", "12.1", "13.1", "14.1", "15.1", 
"15.2", "15.3", "15.4", "15.5", "15.6", "15.7", "15.8", "15.9", 
"15.10", "15.11", "15.12", "15.13", "15.14", "15.15", "15.16", 
"15.17", "15.18", "15.19", "16.1", "17.1", "18.1", "18.2", "18.3", 
"18.4", "18.5", "18.6", "18.7", "18.8", "18.9", "18.10", "18.11", 
"18.12", "18.13", "18.14", "18.15", "18.16", "18.17", "18.18", 
"18.19", "18.20", "18.21", "18.22", "18.23", "18.24", "18.25", 
"18.26", "18.27", "18.28", "18.29", "18.30", "18.31", "18.32", 
"18.33", "18.34", "18.35", "18.36", "18.37", "18.38", "18.39", 
"18.40", "18.41", "18.42", "18.43", "18.44", "18.45", "18.46", 
"18.47", "18.48", "18.49", "18.50", "18.51", "18.52", "18.53", 
"18.54", "18.55", "18.56", "18.57", "18.58", "18.59", "18.60", 
"18.61", "18.62", "18.63", "18.64", "18.65", "18.66", "18.67", 
"18.68", "18.69", "18.70", "18.71", "18.72", "18.73", "18.74", 
"19.1", "19.2", "19.3", "19.4", "19.5", "19.6", "19.7", "2.1", 
"2.2", "2.3", "20.1", "20.2", "20.3", "20.4", "20.5", "20.6", 
"20.7", "20.8", "20.9", "20.10", "20.11", "20.12", "20.13", "20.14", 
"20.15", "20.16", "20.17", "20.18", "20.19", "20.20", "20.21", 
"20.22", "20.23", "20.24", "20.25", "20.26", "20.27", "20.28", 
"20.29", "20.30", "20.31", "20.32", "20.33", "20.34", "20.35", 
"20.36", "20.37", "20.38", "21.1", "21.2", "21.3", "21.4", "21.5", 
"21.6", "21.7", "21.8", "21.9", "21.10", "21.11", "21.12", "21.13", 
"21.14", "21.15", "21.16", "21.17", "21.18", "21.19", "21.20", 
"21.21", "21.22", "21.23", "21.24", "21.25", "21.26", "21.27", 
"21.28", "21.29", "21.30", "21.31", "21.32", "21.33", "21.34", 
"21.35", "21.36", "21.37", "21.38", "21.39", "21.40", "21.41", 
"21.42", "21.43", "21.44", "21.45", "21.46", "21.47", "21.48", 
"21.49", "21.50", "21.51", "21.52", "21.53", "21.54", "21.55", 
"21.56", "21.57", "21.58", "21.59", "21.60", "21.61", "21.62", 
"21.63", "21.64", "21.65", "22.1", "22.2", "23.1", "23.2", "23.3", 
"23.4", "23.5", "23.6", "23.7", "23.8", "24.1", "25.1", "26.1", 
"27.1", "27.2", "27.3", "27.4", "27.5", "27.6", "27.7", "27.8", 
"27.9", "27.10", "27.11", "27.12", "27.13", "27.14", "27.15", 
"27.16", "27.17", "27.18", "27.19", "27.20", "27.21", "27.22", 
"27.23", "28.1", "28.2", "28.3", "28.4", "28.5", "28.6", "28.7", 
"29.1", "3.1", "30.1", "31.1", "32.1", "32.2", "32.3", "32.4", 
"32.5", "32.6", "32.7", "32.8", "32.9", "32.10", "32.11", "32.12", 
"32.13", "32.14", "32.15", "32.16", "32.17", "32.18", "32.19", 
"32.20", "32.21", "32.22", "32.23", "32.24", "32.25", "32.26", 
"32.27", "32.28", "32.29", "32.30", "32.31", "32.32", "32.33", 
"33.1", "33.2", "33.3", "33.4", "33.5", "33.6", "33.7", "33.8", 
"33.9", "33.10", "33.11", "33.12", "33.13", "33.14", "33.15", 
"33.16", "33.17", "33.18", "34.1", "34.2", "34.3", "35.1", "35.2", 
"35.3", "35.4", "35.5", "35.6", "35.7", "35.8", "35.9", "35.10", 
"36.1", "36.2", "36.3", "36.4", "36.5", "36.6", "36.7", "36.8", 
"36.9", "36.10", "36.11", "36.12", "36.13", "36.14", "36.15", 
"36.16", "37.1", "38.1", "39.1", "4.1", "5.1", "5.2", "5.3", 
"5.4", "5.5", "5.6", "5.7", "5.8", "5.9", "5.10", "5.11", "5.12", 
"5.13", "5.14", "5.15", "5.16", "5.17", "5.18", "5.19", "5.20", 
"5.21", "5.22", "5.23", "5.24", "5.25", "5.26", "5.27", "5.28", 
"5.29", "5.30", "5.31", "5.32", "5.33", "5.34", "5.35", "5.36", 
"5.37", "5.38", "5.39", "5.40", "6.1", "7.1", "8.1", "9.1"), class = "factor"), 
    coef = c(0.1349402, 0.1349402, 0.1349402, 0.1349402, 0.1349402, 
    0.1349402, 0.1349402, 0.1349402, 0.1349402, 0.1349402, 0.1349402, 
    0.1349402, 0.1349402, 0.1349402, 0.1349402, 0.1349402, 0.1349402, 
    0.1349402, 0.1349402, 0.1349402), quint = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("[0.0784,0.119]", "(0.119,0.135]", 
    "(0.135,0.147]", "(0.147,0.154]", "(0.154,0.229]"), class = "factor"), 
    stateav53 = c(0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 
    0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 
    0.139, 0.139, 0.139, 0.139)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset ? (see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for your reminder. My apologies for the inconvenience but the data frame I have is quite big so I've attached a screen shot of the first few rows. Would that be sufficient?

Comment: thanks for the update. The best would be to use `dput(head(yourdataframe,20))` and post the exact output into your question. This would help us a lot, and save us time to reproduce your data

Comment: Thank you for your instruction! I have updated the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd create an annotation data frame and use this with geom_text. You can create the variable element with `paste`.

For the legend, I'd create a label column, so that you can then just use this for your aesthetic.

You can then facet by group.

```r
library(tidyverse)

RIalz_data2 <- RIalz_data %>% mutate(stateav53 = 0.149, quint = "(1,2]", group = "2")
RIalz <- bind_rows(RIalz_data, RIalz_data2) %>%
  mutate(quint = str_sub(quint, 2, -2)) %>% 
  separate(quint, c("min", "max"), sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(newquint = paste0(as.numeric(min)*100,"%-",as.numeric(max)*100,"%"))

ann_df <- 
  RIalz %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(quint = unique(newquint), stateav53 = unique(stateav53)) 

ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data=RIalz, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=newquint)) +
  geom_text(data = ann_df, 
            mapping = aes(x=-71.92, y=41.26, 
                          label=paste("State Average:", stateav53*100, "%")), 
                          hjust=0) +
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

helpful answer/thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52107657/7941188

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful suggestion! The paste function works very well! I can't really have the legend out of the map. But my initial question is resolved. Thank you very much for your help!